# Bubble Sort for 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to sort all 2D array elements in c++ using bubble sort, but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){    

int x[4][4],i,k,j;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        cin>>x[i][j];

cout<<"\n\n";

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        for(k=j+1;k<4;k++)
            if(x[i][j]>x[i][k])
            {
                int temp = x[i][j];
                x[i][j] = x[i][k];
                x[i][k] = temp;
            }           

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        cout<<x[i][j]<<"\t";
        cout<<"\n\n";       
    }


cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The thing is, I'm not sure if these elements are sorting correctly. I think I should just put another for loop somewhere, but I don't know where.

Also, is it possible to minimize the code above to use only 2 for loops? I thought that I could but I wasn't exactly sure how I'd do it because the elements of 'j' must be less than 1.

My main problem here though is just sorting all of the elements.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the below which may be surprising, bu works fine, but using qsort instead of bubble sort...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int myfunction (int* i,int* j) { return (*i>*j); }
int main (){    
   int x[4][4],i,k,j;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
         x[i][j] = random()%1000;

   qsort((void*)x, 16, sizeof(int),(int (*)(const void*,const void*))myfunction);

   for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
          cout<<x[i][j]<<"\t";
      cout<<"\n\n";       
   }
}
```

There is a trick here, in as that we are just sorting a one-dimensional array using qsort.   The trick is possible because the memory layout of x[4][4] is 16 consecutive integers, so you can access just as if it was declared as x[16] -- and you can use this fact to also implement a traditional bubble sort, just casting int *y = (int*)x; and then sorting y from (0..15) as it was a one dimensional array.

However I would not recommend this if you are a novice to intermediate programmer in C/C++, as you probably will get it horribly wrong -- also you probably will not get any performance gains in doing so, as the optimizer is pretty good and unrolling loops, and the modern pipe-line CPU are very fast in executing tight loops like your above.

**Update**

As a bubble sort, the following works with only two loops;

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
  for(j=i;j<16;j++)
    if(x[i/4][i%4]>x[j/4][j%4])
    {
        int temp = x[i/4][i%4];
        x[i/4][i%4] = x[j/4][j%4];
        x[j/4][j%4] = temp;
    }
```

If you do insist on having individual loops of each dimension, then this is the right way;

```
for (int ia=0; ia <4; ia++)
  for (int ja=0; ja <4; ja++)
    for (int ib=0; ib <4; ib++)
      for (int jb=0; jb <4; jb++)
        if(x[ia][ib]<x[ja][jb])
        {
            int temp = x[ia][ib];
            x[ia][ib] = x[ja][jb];
            x[ja][jb] = temp;
        }
```

Comment: thanks sir , but The code above is very hard to understand , but I want to sort all elements without using any FUNCTION and I think I just add 1 loop but where and how ?

Comment: I disagree that is is hard to read -- however if you argue that it is bad for compiler optimization and CPU pipe lining then you may be right.  I added two version of pure loops which works as well....

Comment: thank you sir , thats what I need the second one , but the first one is more confused But Are generated it or old answere because Can I think like that way in less than 10 minutes ?! , But I love it thanks again for help

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't proper C++, let me point out a thing:

For this:

```
int temp = x[i][j];
x[i][j] = x[i][k];
x[i][k] = temp;
```

C++ has a built-in function, `std::swap`, declared in header `algorithm`, so you can use:

```
std::swap(x[i][j], x[i][k]);
```

Now, for the algorithm. If you input a matrix like this:

```
16 8 3 2
4 5 15 10
11 12 13 14
1 6 9 7
```

It should output

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Nothing new.

The sorting algorithm should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        int m = i;
        int n = j + 1;
        while (true) {
            if (n == 4) {
                n = 0;
                m++;
                if (m == 4) break; // Stopping condition: n == 4 && m == 4
            }

            if (x[i][j] > x[m][n]) std::swap(x[i][j], x[m][n]);

            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir , first I know swap function but I dont want to use it , seconds about my question is sorting whole array from [0][0] to [last row][last column] , but there is an error in your code,See that output please , not correct !

Comment: @user3457718 I have tested the code I posted and it works just fine. What should be the correct output then?

Comment: see this link please [link](http://ideone.com/RwrabE)

Comment: Your code had a big problem, correct one is http://ideone.com/yausVN